# How to protect Kibana with AWS acocunt signin instead of Cognito signun?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-elasticsearch

I have been able to protect my AWS Elastic Search instance using Cognito by:

- Selecting Enable Amazon Cognito for authentication in cluster configuration
- Setting an access policy where I allow a Cognito Identity Pool IAM role

This works.

But I would prefer to

- Use AWS credentials instead of creating a new user pool with Cognito
- Not have the login page appear when logged in AWS users visit Kibana, instead just having them be logged in

How can I achieve this?

I have tried a variety of settings but haven't been successful. I can see in the access policy example for AWS/IAM users that it should be possible to allow AWS users. But when I add my own account ID, I still get the login page when visiting Kibana as an already logged in user. I have a federated account so don't know what user name or password I am expected to enter. If I disable  Amazon Cognito for authentication in cluster configuration setting, I am instead denied access when visiting Kibana as an already logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

This is a policy I wrote up for someone that wanted to do something similar (IAM User Access along with IP Restrictions).

See if this helps get you going in the right direction:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::OUR_ACCOUNT_ID:role/xxxxx-prod-eb-role",
          "arn:aws:iam::OUR_ACCOUNT_ID:role/xxxx-staging-eb-role"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:eu-west-1:OUR_ACCOUNT_ID:domain/xxxx-xxxxx-poc/*",
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": [
            "52.000.000.07/32",
            "54.00.000.000/32"
         ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```